# Dirac-delta-distribution charge densitity

Tags: electrostatics, charge, dirac-delta-distributions

Are the charge distributions $$\rho(\vec{r})=\frac{Q}{2\pi R^2}\delta(r-R)\delta(\vartheta-\pi/2)$$ and $$\rho(\vec{r})=\frac{Q}{2\pi r^2\sin(\vartheta)}\delta(r-R)\delta(\vartheta-\pi/2)$$ of a charged circle the same? I would say yes because integrating over them gives the same result but is this in general true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since $\delta(r-R)\delta(\vartheta-\pi/2)$ is zero everywhere except $\left(r,\vartheta\right)=\left(R,\theta/2\right)$, we can replace
$$
\frac{Q}{2\pi r^2\sin(\vartheta)}
$$
with its value at $\left(r,\vartheta\right)=\left(R,\theta/2\right)$:
$$
\frac{Q}{2\pi R^2}
$$
If you have a copy of Griffiths E&M he discusses this property of the Dirac delta function (section 1.5.2, equation 1.88, at least in the Third Edition).

Answer (score 4):

Two distributions are *defined* as being equal if, when integrated with respect to an arbitrary test function, they always yield the same result.  In other words, $D_1(r,\theta)$ and $D_2 (r, \theta)$ are equal if for all test functions $f(r, \theta)$, we have
$$
\int D_1(r,\theta) f(r, \theta) = \int D_2(r,\theta) f(r, \theta).
$$
If you have a copy of Griffiths, this is discussed briefly in Section 1.5.2 (Equation 1.93 *et seq.*)

In your case, it is straightforward to evaluate both integrals and show that both are equal to $\frac{Q}{2 \pi R} f(R, \pi/2)$ regardless of your choice of $f$.  Thus, the two distributions are equal.